# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 20): TypeError: _util.base64.tI is not a function. React Native

Tags: javascript, xcode, firebase, react-native, es6-promise

I am building an app using react native, I use firebase as my database. Everything was working fine. I started running the app on my device through Xcode. It worked but now I get this warning on my device and simulator which prevents me from getting data from firebase database. the warning is

**"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 20):
TypeError: _util.base64.tI is not a function. (In '_util.base64.tI(t, !1)', '_util.base64.tI' is undefined)"**

I don't know where did this (_util.base64) come from. I guess the problem has to do with this code part (the promise) as when I remove this part it works fine but unable to get data without it. can anyone help?

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("Appointments")
      .orderBy("Timing", "desc")
      .limit(2)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const list = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const { Speciality, Date, TimeSlot } = doc.data();
          list.push({
            id: doc.id,
            Speciality,
            Date,
            TimeSlot,
          });
        });

        setAppointments(list);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

[This is the warning that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L35Me.png)

[Those are my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMjeW.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve it was:

run `expo install firebase`

Create a config.js file where I put my  Firebase credentials:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
var firebaseConfig = {
  //Your Firebase credentials
};

var app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = app;
```

And import that file wherever I need it

```
import { db } from '../config';
//Here's where I call firestore (You can also do this in the config file)
import 'firebase/firestore';

db.firestore().
collection('your_collection').get().then(
    //The stuff you want to do
);
```

At least, now it works for me.

In this [link](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/) you can see the oficial expo with firebase documentation